# Find last available date if date does not exist in other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, isin

Suppose that you have two data frames which can be created using code below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'start_date': ['2021-07-02', '2021-07-09',
                                        '2021-07-16', '2021-07-23',
                                        '2021-07-30'],
                         'end_date': ['2021-07-09', '2021-07-16',
                                      '2021-07-23', '2021-07-30',
                                      '2021-08-06']})

price_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': ['2021-07-01', '2021-07-03',
                                       '2021-07-08', '2021-07-10',
                                       '2021-07-16', '2021-07-22',
                                       '2021-07-30', '2021-07-31',
                                       '2021-08-06'],
                              'price': [47, 62, 107, 171, 30, 154, 42,
                                        143, 131]})
```

adding conversion to datetime using code below

```
df1['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start_date'])
df1['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['end_date'])
price_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(price_df['date'])
```

Using `df1['start_date'].isin(price_df['date'])` I can check if dates in column `start_date` of data frame `df1` exists in data frame `price_df`. In case that is not true I want to replace the `start_date` with last available date from `price_df`. Similar process needs to be performed on column `end_date` of data frame `df1`. Finally prices can be extracted using a join.

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| start_date |  end_date  | start_price | end_price |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| 01/07/2021 | 08/07/2021 |          47 |       107 |
| 08/07/2021 | 16/07/2021 |         107 |        30 |
| 16/07/2021 | 22/07/2021 |          30 |       154 |
| 22/07/2021 | 30/07/2021 |         154 |        42 |
| 30/07/2021 | 06/08/2021 |          42 |       131 |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I attempted this code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['start_date'] = np.where(df1['start_date']
                             .isin(price_df['date']),
                             df1['start_date'],
                             price_df[
                                 price_df.date < df1['start_date']][
                                 'date'].max())
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```py
df1[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df1[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
price_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(price_df['date'])

price_df = price_df.sort_values('date')

df1[['start_date', 'start_price']] = pd.merge_asof(df1, price_df, left_on='start_date', right_on='date')[['date', 'price']]
df1[['end_date', 'end_price']] = pd.merge_asof(df1, price_df, left_on='end_date', right_on='date')[['date', 'price']]

df1[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df1[['start_date', 'end_date']].apply(lambda col: col.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

```
print(df1)

   start_date    end_date  start_price  end_price
0  01/07/2021  08/07/2021           47        107
1  08/07/2021  16/07/2021          107         30
2  16/07/2021  22/07/2021           30        154
3  22/07/2021  30/07/2021          154         42
4  30/07/2021  06/08/2021           42        131
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to replace start dates in `df1` that aren't in `price_df` with dates from `price_df`.

Comment: @semblable Don't understand want you mean.

Comment: The `start_date` column in your output doesn't match the `start_date` column in the expected output.

Comment: @semblable you are right.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh please add the following lines too so the date column is fixed.
`df1['start_date'] = pd.merge_asof(df1, price_df, left_on='start_date', right_on='date')['date']`
`df1['end_date'] = pd.merge_asof(df1, price_df, left_on='end_date', right_on='date')['date']`